# How to redirect wget output into another file (Only the response code/error )

Tags: linux, wget, redirection

Please help me on writing(redirecting) the wget output on a file(i just wanted the status or below lines on /tmp/logfile.log).

Please find my output

```
$ wget  --no-check-certificate -nv --spider --tries=5 -i url_list.txt >/tmp/logfile.log
2016-08-15 15:23:14 URL: http://25.188.8.5:26005/southamericaend/ 200 OK
2016-08-15 15:23:14 URL: http://25.188.8.5:26005/saendpages/pages/WindowApicross?wsdl 200 OK
Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to redirect stderr as well. Change the end of the command to

```
2>&1 >tmp/logfile.log
```